# proper use of get_records in moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I wonder how can I find my moodle's database contents.

I want to elaborate users etc.

My first try is with PHP code using `global $DB` but there is an error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function get_record() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 3

I use the `getrecord()` function but I didn't do it right.

Can anybody help me? The name of my database is "base".

> Note: moodle version is 2.7.2

Answer (score 1):

This is an example that should allow you to access the Moodle DB.

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config.php'; // Insert as many '/../' as you need to get from the subdirectory your file is in, back up to Moodle's config.php

function my_function() {
  global $DB;
  $record = $DB->get_record('user', array('id' => 2));
  var_dump($record);
}

my_function();
```